# Some DLLs missing from Modules Window

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

After couple of hours of looking in the internet without succeed.

I am working in visual studio 2013. 
I have a solution with c# project that call c++.

I put break point in a function in the c++ project and got the following warning:

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

So I open *Debug → Modules Window* to check the symbols. And I saw that the DLL of the C++ project does not appears in the Modules Window.

The application is running correctly.

I looked at the dump file of the application and it took the dll from the right place.

I have an older version of this solution and there I can put break point. 
If I compare the content of the Modules Window of the two solutions, the old one contains much more dlls.

Any Idea for what and where I should look for the solution?

Comment: If DLL is being loaded dynamically or delay-loaded, it won't load the symbols until the point where loading of image is required. Are you saying that the dll is loaded and done its job and yet breakpoint is not hit?

Comment: Yes the dll done is job. And I can see it was loaded in the dump file. But break point is not hit and I can't see him (and some other dlls) in the Modules Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you need to [enable mixed mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/kbaht4dh(v=vs.120)) to allow you to debug in both C# and C++ at the same time.
This is a project level setting so that would explain why your older project works.

The basic steps should be something like:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the C++ project and select Properties.
2. In the Property Pages dialog box, expand the Configuration Properties node, and then select Debugging.
3. Set Debugger Type to Mixed or Auto.
4. In Solution Explorer, right-click the C# project and select Properties.
5. Select Debug
6. In Enable Debugger section choose Enable native code Debugging

Comment: It was already set to Auto I changed it to fixed and i still can't debug

Comment: Have you got "Enable native code debugging" ticked in the C# project debug settings? Although, I'm not sure if that's a setting in newer VS versions only.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are not running in  release mode.

delete  bin/obj folder

clean solution and rebuild it.

Hope this will help you